# How do I update json data in postgres sql in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

my data structure schema is like

```
users(
  id serial primary key,
  data json
);
```

I want to update `data` key.

I'm using [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) library and So far I have tried something like this:

```
pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
    var queryString = "UPDATE users SET data =" + myNewJsonData + " WHERE  id = " + userIdToEdit + ";";
    client.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
        done();
        if (err) {
            res.send("Failed to update user data ");
            throw err;
        } else {
            res.send("Successfully updated user data!! ");
        }
    });
});
```

this is not working, I'm getting error `invalid input syntax for type json`

Can anyone help, Thanks.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The right one should be: Here's the complete `UPDATE`, what is wrong with the syntax around the JSON column? And you don't even include what `myNewJsonData` is.

Comment: Its because I'm not very sure with my approach here.

Comment: But your question is about the syntax issue, not the approach. Strictly speaking, the approach will work, if you escape everything correctly. But that's a separate question altogether.

Comment: ah man you are right, it was syntax issue, got it working finally. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it was a syntax error, All I had to do stringfy json data and put that in 'quotes'

```
pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
var newJsonDataStringyfied = JSON.stringify(myNewJsonData)
var queryString = "UPDATE users SET data = '" + newJsonDataStringyfied + "' WHERE  id = " + userIdToEdit + ";";
    client.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
        done();
        if (err) {
            res.send("Failed to update user data ");
            throw err;
        } else {
            res.send("Successfully updated user data!! ");
        }
    });
});
```